# External login with Google/GitHub on the new Spring authorization server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I have an Angular client app and I am implementing a Spring authorization server. I want to provide external login with Google/GitHub on the new Spring authorization server and redirect to the Angular client app with authorization code.

In the `spring-authorization-server` GitHub repository provided a [federated identity authorization server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver) but the problem is that after successfully login with Google they do not provide success URL. I want to redirect my Angular client app with authorization code with success URL.

Is there any sample code available with Angular and federated identity authorization server for Google/Github Social Login?

Comment: Show your configuration of your authorization server.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an official sample demonstrating that combination of concepts.

However, in addition to the [federated identity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver) sample, you can take a look at my [bff-demo](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/bff-demo/samples) branch and [this webinar](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) from March 2022 where we demonstrate some patterns for integrating a SPA with SAS.

Note that the [documented recommendation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297) is to use the Backend for Frontend pattern. Although it is possible, I don't recommend building an Angular client that directly receives access/refresh tokens.